# Registering WPF Logical UiElemnts with click

Tags: c#, wpf

So, I'm trying to add an authorization administration to an existing `WPF` aplication. The aim is to allow administrator handpick UI elements (textboxes, buttons..) and assign who can use them.
All forms inherit from `MetroBaseWindow`, and there is too many forms to add events to each control or form, so I need to do this 'Globaly'.

The problem for me is registering the click on `UIElement` and retrieving it.

So far I've registered to an event..

```
public class MetroBaseWindow : Window
{
    // ...

    public MetroBaseWindow()
    {
        ...
        this.PreviewMouseDown += RegisterControlOnClick;
    }
}
```

Then I retrieved the position.

```
private void RegisterControlOnClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Point pt = e.GetPosition((UIElement)sender);

    hitResultsList.Clear();

    VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(this, null,
        new HitTestResultCallback(MyHitTestResult),
        new PointHitTestParameters(pt));

    if (hitResultsList.Count > 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Number of Visuals Hit: " + hitResultsList.Count);
    }
}

public HitTestResultBehavior MyHitTestResult(HitTestResult result)
{
    hitResultsList.Add(result.VisualHit);

    return HitTestResultBehavior.Continue;
}
```

And tried to use `VisualTree` to retrieve those elements. But when clicking a combobox, all that is returned are border elements, for textbox a textview, etc...

How do I get the logical elements directly under the cursor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i Figured it out...still needs some tweaks but here goes the code:

```
        List<DependencyObject> hitResultsList = new List<DependencyObject>();

    private void RegisterControlOnClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Point pt = e.GetPosition((UIElement)sender);

        VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(this, new HitTestFilterCallback(MyHitTestFilter), new HitTestResultCallback(MyHitTestResult), new PointHitTestParameters(pt));

    }

    public HitTestResultBehavior MyHitTestResult(HitTestResult result)
    {
        return HitTestResultBehavior.Continue;
    }

    public HitTestFilterBehavior MyHitTestFilter(DependencyObject o)
    {
        if (o.GetType().IsSubclassOf(typeof(ContentControl)))
        {
            hitResultsList.Add(o);
            ((Control)o).Background = Brushes.Red;

        }

        return HitTestFilterBehavior.Continue;
    }
```